# How to Exit Threads Safely

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I'm having to work with Threads (First time), and noticed that when I close the form with ALT + F4 The thread continues to run. This is definitely not expected results, as I need this thread to stop running on exit. I currently have:

```
    public void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs E)
    {
        Continue = false;
    }


    Boolean Continue = true;

    int MouseX = Cursor.Position.X;
    int MouseY = Cursor.Position.Y;
    Point MousePosition;
    public static void LockMouse()
    {
        Form1 Form = new Form1();
        while (Form.Continue)
        {
            Form.MousePosition.X = 0;
            Form.MousePosition.Y = 0;
            Cursor.Position = Form.MousePosition;
        }


    }
```

and this is thread is being created by:

```
    public void CreteThread()
    {
        Thread Worker = new Thread(LockMouse);
        Worker.Start();
    }
```

I have noticed that the thread stays open when ALT + F4, which is entering a  complete mouse lock which is not intended! It seems the form isn't reaching the Closing function?

*I'd like to point out, as some users may see this as possible malicious code & Downvote accordingly or request closures for the wrong reason. This application is being created and for use by myself & Will not be distributed*

Comment: declare your thread as a Background one and it will be destroyed when all other threads ends:

[IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I didn't see any malicious code here ?

Comment: anyhow ... nothing related to your first question ... don't use a while loop to get the coordinates ... use the Eventhandler [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx) this will be more performant and you get rid of your thread.

Comment: @JPVenson Will have a look, thanks for the reference!

Comment: You'r Welcome ... added as Awnser.

Comment: @mysticcode It's an "each to their own" viewing stance, as i've seen a few cursor manipulations in a loop with comments in the line of malicious, wanted to state this is not the case with this environment

Comment: There are a lot of facts that will be against this procedure. Just the fact that you'r creating an Thread for this work will cost a lot of Performance. Because the thread will run on the same level then even more importierend things. That brings us the the question of the Need. Is it really so imported to get an update all 1-2 ms? because it will run this fast. next thing is why are you trying to Lock the cursor? this is something i would Never advice. This is a "evil" behavor. If you want to disallow the user to use your form, Lock the form not the user.

Comment: @JPVenson I can understand the outlook of being "evil", it's not the form which is the problem. It's more over a case of experimenting on my own methods of secondary password authentication once past Windows Logins, mainly due to my recent position, my machine will at times hold local copies of databases which are in a production environment. Essentially, Focus is going to be locked into this form to ask for a secondary password. If correct, Stop the MSSQL service, decrypt the files and allow access. If an incorrect password is entered, Allow access without decrypting the files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68595/discussion-between-jpvenson-and-daryl-gill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your thread as a Background one and it will be destroyed when all other threads ends: IsBackground.

anyhow ... nothing related to your first question ... don't use a while loop to get the coordinates ... use the Eventhandler MouseMove this will be more performant and you get rid of your thread.